# use a4j:queue for events synchronization

Tags: events, jsf, richfaces, queue, ajax4jsf

I have an input text and a button on the form.
 I process event `onchange` for input text and `onclick` for button.
 If the user changes the text and then click the button 2 events fired and sometimes they are processed simultaneously.
I would like `onclick` to be processed after `onchange` completed.
 For this I use `<a4j:queue name="myQueue"/>` and mark events with `<a4j:queue name="myQueue"/>` like this:

```
<a4j:queue name="myQueue"/>
    ...
<h:inputText id="dateFromText" value="#{flowScope.fileSearchCriteria.fromDateStr}">
          <a4j:support event="onchange" eventsQueue="myQueue" reRender="datePanel1" 
          actionListener="#{fileSearchCriteria.changeTextFromDate}"/>
</h:inputText>
    ....
<h:commandButton id="fileInSearch" action="fileInSearch"
        value="#{resourceBundle.searchIn}" type="submit">
        <a4j:support eventsQueue="myQueue" event="onclick"/>
</h:commandButton>
...
```

And as a result, `onclick` is processed not every time after `onchange`.

Answer (score 1):

You should have two events each time, onchange and onclick.  But, I'd recommend to switch to a4j:commadnButton instead of using h:commandButton with a4j:support inside.

Comment: I've tried a4j:commandButton - no effect. What do you mean under "two events each time"?

Comment: You are going to have two events, in the order you activated the components. Here is a good article on queues that might help: http://www.jsfcentral.com/articles/richfaces_queue.html